# H2O adding extra neuron to read-in

Tags: r, machine-learning, deep-learning, h2o

I have a train-dataset (forest cover type) which has 10 continuous variables and then 2 categorical (with 40 and 4 levels). So it seems to me that my read-in layer should contain 54 neurons (I am using 1-of-C). Similarly I found another version of the data ([here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Covertype)), which indeed claims 54 attributes.

Below is my representation of my model:
[image]

**The problem is that when I use H2O in R; it tells me I have 204,707 params (and 56 neurons in the first layer). I don't understand why it breaks (or how) the categorical into N+1? I checked and there are no missing values**

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that H2O does add an (NA) class to deal with missing values (hence we get N+1). Which is a bit strange as I have none.

Comment: Yes, H2O adds an NA class for all categoricals -- this is because if the test set contains a new category (not present in the training set), then that value will have somewhere to go.  Although this is not strictly needed for training, it is helpful if you want to productionize the models.